# Building for 10.8.5

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I am building an app that works fine in most OS X versions, but I have users who want to use it on 10.8.5

I have built with a deployment target of 10.8 and I get crashes on launch in 10.8.5:

```
Process:         Test [301]
Path:            /Users/USER/Desktop/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test
Identifier:      com.map-pin.Test
Version:         2.33 (3330)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [124]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2016-02-09 14:17:57.391 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F2560)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000060

VM Regions Near 0x60:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000108374000-0000000108423000 [  700K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Desktop/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c380670 strlen + 16
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83a76d81 +[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:] + 86
2   com.map-pin.Test                0x000000010837c038 -[AppDelegate getDef] + 120
3   com.map-pin.Test                0x00000001083be38f -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 751
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a188eda _CFXNotificationPost + 2554
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83a53796 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8507652d -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 292
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85076266 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 216
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff85073452 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 566
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8507304c -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 351
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83a6d05b -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 308
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff83a6cebd _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 106
12  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8e906e68 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 307
13  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8e906cc9 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 37
14  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8e906b89 aeProcessAppleEvent + 318
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8eb0c709 AEProcessAppleEvent + 100
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8506f836 _DPSNextEvent + 1456
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8506edf2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff850661a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8500abd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
20  com.map-pin.Test                0x00000001083ee8e2 main + 34
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8de5a7e1 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a7f06d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c394f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c394ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c37f191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a7f0d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86157dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff861579ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a7f06d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c394f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c394ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c37f191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a7f06d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c394f1c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c394ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c37f191 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000000ffffffff  rbx: 0x0000000000000060  rcx: 0x0000000000000060  rdx: 0x0000000000000060
  rdi: 0x0000000000000060  rsi: 0x00007fff858b9059  rbp: 0x00007fff5788ae30  rsp: 0x00007fff5788ae08
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fff5788ad98  r10: 0x00007fe7f2c3c8c0  r11: 0x00007fff83a76d2b
  r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000004  r15: 0x00007fff7256d780
  rip: 0x00007fff8c380670  rfl: 0x0000000000010286  cr2: 0x0000000000000060
Logical CPU: 0
```

Is there a good way to figure out whats going on here?

Comment: Please include the code of the `-[AppDelegate getDef]` method, which is what's crashing here.

Comment: In your question, not in a comment. Use the "edit" button under your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to track down a few methods that were not available until 10.9.x by going through the traces.